# Compilation problems

Tags: compiling

When I compile my document with XeLaTex, I obtain errors messages I never had before upgrading my texlive distribution from 2015 to 2016. On the first page of my document, I have the mention "scrplain" and the number "1" appears on the right. How can I fix that ? This is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}


\frontmatter


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Always nice if you report the exact error message as well. I get an error  with TL2015 as well (`Command \manualmark already defined`, which comes from loading both `scrpage2` and `classicthesis`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classicthesis does already load the `scrlayer-scrpage` which is the successor to `scrpage2`. Your document compiles after removing the `\usepackage{scrpage2}`.

Proof:
ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty

Comment: I've just removed the \usepackage{scrpage2} and it works. Many thanks for your help!